# Automatic swapping of values among cells if a single cell value is changed in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, swap

So I've an excel table as

[image]

If I change the value of 3 to 1, the value 1 should automatically change to 3. Thus the final table should be like

[image]

Comment: `the final table should be like` OK. What have you tried and where are you stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was trying to create a macro but don't know how to approach it or perhaps if there's a simpler way to solve it. I know the sub for swapping values but don't know how to traverse an entire column of values & update the value to be swapped with.

Comment: I suppose the challenge is that when I enter the value in the cell to be updated, how do I get the other cell to be updated following the logic of setting the value of the old value of the cell which I updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this code to be put in the worksheet code pane (myAddress set as A1:A4 implies column A row 1 to 4, which needs to be modified according to the user's worksheet)

```
Option Explicit

Dim myVal As Variant
Dim okChange As Boolean
Const myAddress As String = "A1:A4"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    If Not okChange Then Exit Sub

    Dim f As Range
        Set f = Range(myAddress).Find(what:=target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=target)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            f.Value = myVal
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    okChange = False
    Select Case True
        Case target.CountLarge > 1    
        Case Intersect(target, Range(myAddress)) Is Nothing    
        Case Else
            myVal = target.Value
            okChange = True    
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I'm assuming the Table is called `Table1` and the column you wish the sub to affect is called `Column1`. Edit the code to your requirement as necessary.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Exit sub if edited value isn't in the desired range:
If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[Column1]")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim OldValue As Variant, changeCell as Range

'Find the Old value of the cell
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Undo
    OldValue = Target.Value
    .Undo
End With 'Application

'Find the value to be changed:
Set ChangeCell = ExceptRange(Range("Table1[Column1]"), Target).Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

'Edit to the Old value
If Not ChangeCell Is Nothing Then ChangeCell.Value = OldValue

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function ExceptRange(Rng As Range, Except As Range) As Range
'The opposite of Intersect
Dim a As Long, Confirmed() As Range
For a = 1 To Rng.Cells.Count
    If Intersect(Rng.Cells(a), Except) Is Nothing Then
        If ExceptRange Is Nothing Then
            Set ExceptRange = Rng.Cells(a)
        Else
            Set ExceptRange = Union(ExceptRange, Rng.Cells(a))
        End If
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Your attempt is not bad, however your code fails: **(a)** there is a parenthesis missing in the `Intersect`-statement. **(b)** there is a `Set` missing at the `Find`-command  **(c)** `Find` needs to search for the *new* value, not the old **(d)** You should catch the case that there was no matching value and therefore `ChangeCell` is Nothing  **(e)** You need to set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before you assign the old value to `ChangeCell`, else the Change event is triggered again

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks for the feedback, edited accordingly plus added my `ExceptRange` function to avoid identifying `Target` as the cell to be changed back to the old value.

Comment: I wonder, will it work if after your OldValue has the value, then `Set c = Columns(1).Find(Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=Target): If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Value = OldValue` ? Please CMIIW. But this must assume that the data in column A is all unique.